# How to create the interface to an OS

Tags: operating-system

The question says it all.  When I say interface, I mean what the user interacts with completely.  I've got an extensive C background and know enough to make a rudimentary OS but I'd rather not reinvent the OS.  Using a linux build (or something else if better) such as Arch I'd like to know the most appropriate and extensive way to be the lowest layer over the OS.

The closest example I can think of to what I'd like is how Android Phones have perfectly usable interfaces with user permissions handled by the OS but it's a modified linux kernel.  Is modifying the kernel the best way to go about it, and if so any pointers to setting up any sort of visual system such as OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

On most systems, one accesses the operating system by triggering an exception of some kind. Usually a processor has some kind of "trigger an exception that calls a system service" instruction. Each system service is identified by a number and that number is passed as either an operating to the exception or as a register value (depending upon the processor).

The normal practice is to have a wrapper function for each system service designed to be called from some high level language. The wrapper unpacks the parameters (usually on the stack) and sets up the hardware registers using those parameters. Then it triggers the exception to invoke the system service. This causes to processor to enter a protected mode and execute the system service.  When the system service completes, the wrapper extracts the return values from hardware registers, then packs the result in to the return parameters for the caller.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you!  I understand the idea of how an operating system works and about interrupts and such.  I definitely will need to learn a bit more if I need to delve DEEP into the OS, but I was hoping there was somewhere I could insert myself in at the C or assembly level to call what would display my interface.  Any ideas?